# How to achiave this:MYSQL SELECT if true select a else select b?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select `user.*` if `chat.chat_type IS NULL`, but if `chat.chat_type = 1`

I want to select group.*

```
SELECT    
    CASE
        WHEN chat.chat_type IS NULL THEN  user.*
        WHEN chat.chat_type =1 THEN  group.*
    END,
    x,y 
FROM `chat` LEFT JOIN group ...
```

How I can achieve this?

Comment: It does not work like that. A query is fixed. Use seperate queries. Or  build the query string manually and execute it dynamically

Comment: This kind of problem is often symptomatic of poor design

Comment: What criteria do you join the tables on? It should be something like `FROM chat c LEFT JOIN ``group`` g ON c.group_id = g.group_id` to have proper foreign key constraints. Same for the user table. So it's easy to join the two tables and no need to check the chat_type in my opinion. (It seems redundant, because either `chat.group_id` or `chat.user_id` will be filled anyway.)

Comment: I agreed with the above comments: a function that returns a result of two possible distinct types depending on a column value sounds like a design problem.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner my design is like below:
In chat table I have `from`,`to`,`chat_type` AND `message` columns.If chat_type is NULL,It means that it is one to one chat (It means `to` is user_id and  I need join users table),if chat_type is 1 it means it is group chat and I need join group table and `to` is group_id.So how can I implement with that?

Comment: Okay, that's not ideal, but can still be worked with of course. Please see my answer on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database design as described is not so good, because you have an ID in your chat table that can either be a user ID or a group ID. Thus you cannot have a constraint (foreign key) on this column, which makes it possible to put any value in there, i.e. even an ID that doesn't exist.

Anyway, with the design given, to get either user or group you outer join both tables on the conditions you already mentioned. Then use `COALESCE` to see whether you got a user or a group in the result row.

```
select c.from, coalesce(u.name, g.name) as to_name
from chat c
left join usr u on c.chat_type is null and c.to = u.user_id
left join grp g on c.chat_type = 1 and c.to = g.group_id
where c.chat_type is null or c.chat_type = 1;
```

Comment: I have checked manually when user insert to chat than it exists or not.
How should I need desing tablle columns if I plan to create new types of chat in the future?( for example `to` column will be able to be other things beside group_id and  user_id )?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Union:

```
SELECT user.* from user join ... where chat.chat_type is null
Union 
SELECT `Group`.* from `Group` join .... where chat.chat_type =1
```

if user and Group have a different number of column, you have to use a Default where you have less columns.

Hint: because Group is a Keyword, you should rename your table

Comment: Is that can be big problem if I didnt change Group table name and use it always with `` ?

Comment: @IbrahimHasanov It should not be a big Problem if you ever escape it

Comment: Group and user has different columns and different column names,Is that can be slow 
WHEN chat.chat_type IS NULL THEN  user.profileimg
WHEN chat.chat_type=1 THEN Group.group_profileimg
     END
     as profileimg,
WHEN chat.chat_type IS NULL THEN  user.firstname
WHEN chat.chat_type=1 THEN Group.name
     END
     as firstname
is not it slow to check WHENs each time?I think this query will solve problem but I am worry about speed